# csv file print columnwise raw values for values greater than 0.5

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a csv file contains follwing matrix

```
   A1   A2    A3   A4
B1 0.2  0.3   0.7  .5
B2 0.5  0.55  0.4  0.6
B3 0.9  0.13  0.5  0.16
B4 0.2  0.4   0.6  0.8
```

I want my output for values greater than 0.5 in below format

```
A1 B2 B3
A2 B2
A3 B1 B3 B4
```

as follows please help me with the same.

here is what I have tried

```
import csv

ifile  = open('gene.matrix.csv', "rb")
reader = csv.reader(ifile)

rownum = 0
for row in reader:
    # Save header row.
    if rownum == 0:
        header = row
    else:
        colnum = 0
        for col in row:
            print '%-8s: %s' % (header[colnum], col)
            colnum += 1

    rownum += 1

ifile.close()
```

Comment: Can you clarify how you want your data, those values > .5?

Comment: i actually dont want the values I want to use values as filter to the data so loop will start column -wise say start for column A1 will check the list and give me the values as corresponding row headers as output so for A1 my ourput will be ['A1','B2','B3'] ..output can be in any format csv,text etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with something like this :

```
reader = csv.DictReader(ifile)
k = 0.5
for r in reader:
    ivd = {v: k for k, v in r.items()}
    print [r['']] + [ivd[i] for i in r.values()[1:] if float(i)>k]
```

Comment: getting errorAttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: I am not an expert of python so it would be great if you can help full solution ..I would take csv file as input

Comment: make sure you use the DictReader and not Reader in my sample. That's why you had an error.

Comment: import csv
ifile='gene.matrix.csv'
reader = csv.DictReader(ifile)
reader = csv.reader(ifile)

k = 0.5
for r in reader:
    ivd = {v: k for k, v in r.items()}
    print [r['']] + [ivd[i] for i in r.values()[1:] if float(i)>k]

Comment: data/untitled1.py", line 15, in <module>
    ivd = {v: k for k, v in r.items()}
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively if you have [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), the index/column should be easy to get:

```
In [2]: import pandas as pd

# df = pd.read_csv('gene.matrix.csv', delimiter='\s+')
In [3]: df = pd.read_clipboard()  # from your sample

# simply do "df >= 0.5" can locate the values
# .T is just doing a transpose for the correct index/column you expect
# stack() to Pivot a level of the (possibly hierarchical) column labels
In [4]: groups = df[df >= 0.5].T.stack()

In [5]: groups
Out[5]:
A1  B2    0.50
    B3    0.90
A2  B2    0.55
A3  B1    0.70
    B3    0.50
    B4    0.60
A4  B1    0.50
    B2    0.60
    B4    0.80
dtype: float64
```

One way to get your desired output:

```
# store required output into a dict key/value list
In [6]: result = {}

In [7]: for i in groups.index:
   ...:     if i[0] in result:
   ...:         result[i[0]].append(i[1])
   ...:     else:
   ...:         result[i[0]] = [i[1]]
   ...:

In [8]: result
Out[8]:
{'A1': ['B2', 'B3'],
 'A2': ['B2'],
 'A3': ['B1', 'B3', 'B4'],
 'A4': ['B1', 'B2', 'B4']}

# to print the expected output... note dict is unordered (you can use OrderedDict)
In [9]: for k, v in result.items():
   ...:     print k, " ".join(v)
   ...:
A1 B2 B3
A3 B1 B3 B4
A2 B2
A4 B1 B2 B4
```

---

**Edit**:

To write the result to a Text file line by line, simply do:

```
with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
    for k, v in result.items():
        f.write("%s %s\n" % (k, " ".join(v)))
```

Probably I have over complicated things in your example, but it surely one way to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your help I have just provided a small snippet of my data ..actually my dataset contain 50,000 rows and 16 columns ..and I want column wise ..my input would be csv file only

Comment: @AlokJha with that amount of dataset, I would really suggest using a library like Pandas, locating the values is fairly straight forward (as you see in part 1). The second part is just how you present or use your column/index wise... which you haven't mentioned, so I simply print them out as of your expectation.

Comment: @AlokJha ok, simply do: `df  = pd.read_csv(FILE_NAME, delimiter="\s+")`, I have edited the answer to show that line, you can read more about `read_csv` from [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: depending your delimiter, you may use "\s+" for spaces wise, or "\t" for tab delimited csv

Comment: kind of worked getting inertial few lines of results and then last few lines ...is there a way to save my results in text of csv file,,,

Comment: do you understand the meaning of CSV (Comma separated values)... the result is clearly not in this format

Comment: @AlokJha also you should put some effort in resolving this question. The question you ask is how to do the output in desired format.  Any other question should really be asked in a separated SO.

I would appreciate if you take my advice, learn more about the Python basics, without completely rely on other's answer.

Also if any of our answers has provided what you expected and you think its a good fit, please accept the answer.